# Gravity Forms get Image from a previous Input page to display inside a HTML Block

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

How can I display inside a HTML Block an Image that has been uploaded in the previous page of the same form.

I Want to display a customized html layout prior submission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few options here. If you're looking to get your hands dirty, Gravity Forms has a robust code snippet for doing this here:

https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_pre_render/#3-populate-field-with-values-from-earlier-page

If you're looking for a point-and-click solution, check out [Gravity Forms Preview Submission](https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-preview-submission/) which lets you do this by adding any HTML field on your form and including the merge tag to your File Upload field.

[image: HTML field with File Upload preview]